# Attach to Process Id Error - Timed out waiting for debug server to connect

Tags: python, visual-studio, remote-debugging, attach-to-process

I m currently doing the remote development from Linux machine. I have mounted the remote code to Visual studio code with remote-ssh extension successfully.

When I try to debug with Attach using Process Id. I'm seeing "Timed out waiting for debug server to connect." Error.

I have set the python2.7 interpreter from remote machine in VS code. With default launch.json when I run debug I'm able to see the process Ids and selected one. It throws timeout error.

**Launch json :**  [Launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJxqC.png)

**Log snippet:**

```
I+00000.030: Injector[PID=13037] output:
             0x00007f8f5e44a923 in ?? () from /lib64/libc.so.6

I+00000.030: Injector[PID=13037] output:
             The target architecture is set automatically (currently i386:x86-64)

I+00000.030: Injector[PID=13037] output:
             

I+00000.030: Injector[PID=13037] output:
             stderr: No symbol "dlopen" in current context.

I+00000.030: Injector[PID=13037] output:
             No symbol "DoAttach" in current context.

I+00000.030: Injector[PID=13037] output:
             

I+00000.030: Injector[PID=13037] exited.

I+00000.030: All debug servers disconnected; waiting for remaining sessions...

E+00000.030: /handling #2 request "attach" from Client[1]/
             Traceback (most recent call last):
               File "/home/vssetup/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/common/messaging.py", line 1062, in __init__
                 raise self
             MessageHandlingError: Timed out waiting for debug server to connect.
             
             Stack where logged:
               File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
                 self.__bootstrap_inner()
               File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
                 self.run()
               File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
                 self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
               File "/home/vssetup/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/common/messaging.py", line 1510, in _run_handlers
                 handler()
               File "/home/vssetup/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/common/messaging.py", line 747, in _handle
                 result = handler(self)
               File "/home/vssetup/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/adapter/components.py", line 95, in lock_and_handle
                 return f(self, message)
               File "/home/vssetup/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/adapter/clients.py", line 199, in handle
                 f(self, request)
               File "/home/vssetup/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/adapter/clients.py", line 514, in attach_request
                 sub_pid,
               File "/home/vssetup/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/common/messaging.py", line 560, in cant_handle
                 return self.error(MessageHandlingError, *args, **kwargs)
               File "/home/vssetup/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/common/messaging.py", line 546, in error
                 exc = exc_type(reason, self, silent)  # will log it
               File "/home/vssetup/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/common/messaging.py", line 1064, in __init__
                 log.swallow_exception()
               File "/home/vssetup/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/common/log.py", line 218, in swallow_exception
                 _exception(format_string, *args, **kwargs)
             

D+00000.030: /handling #2 request "attach" from Client[1]/
             Client[1] <-- {
                 "seq": 5, 
                 "type": "response", 
                 "request_seq": 2, 
                 "success": false, 
                 "command": "attach", 
                 "message": "Timed out waiting for debug server to connect."
             }

E+00000.030: /handling #2 request "attach" from Client[1]/
             Handler 'handle' (file u'/home/vssetup/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/adapter/components.py', line 91)
             couldn't handle #2 request "attach" from Client[1]:
             Timed out waiting for debug server to connect.

D+00000.030: Client[1] --> {
                 "seq": 3, 
                 "type": "request", 
                 "command": "disconnect", 
                 "arguments": {
                     "restart": false
                 }
             }

I+00000.030: /handling #3 request "disconnect" from Client[1]/
             client requested "disconnect"; finalizing Session[1].

D+00000.030: /handling #3 request "disconnect" from Client[1]/
             Client[1] <-- {
                 "seq": 6, 
                 "type": "event", 
                 "event": "terminated"
             }

I+00000.030: /handling #3 request "disconnect" from Client[1]/
             Session[1] finalized.

D+00000.030: /handling #3 request "disconnect" from Client[1]/
             Client[1] <-- {
                 "seq": 7, 
                 "type": "response", 
                 "request_seq": 3, 
                 "success": true, 
                 "command": "disconnect"
             }
```